# How to change a Windows service installation directory at install time?

Tags: c#, windows, service, visual-studio-2015, installation

I built a Windows service (in Visual Studio 2015) and I need the user to select the directory where to install but at installation time I need to add a subfolder to the provided directory. Normally I get the installation directory with `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` but I cannot change it. Is there any method or properties I can change in `BeforeInstall` method for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a few days of searching but it was actually easy.
To do that you need to

- Right-click your setup project and select `View`->`File System`.
- Right-click `application folder` and select `Add`->`Folder`.
- Name your new folder.
- Move all the needed files from `application folder` to your new folder.

That's pretty much it.

As a bonus here is some code to help you install the same service twice using one installer. The installer sets the services recovery mode, service permissions, access permissions, rewrites some config file and start both services. The uninstall part uninstalls both services.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace MyService
{
    partial class ProjectInstaller
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary> 
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller = new ServiceProcessInstaller();
            this.MyServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller();
            // 
            // MyServiceProcessInstaller
            // 
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalService;
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller.Password = null;
            this.MyServiceProcessInstaller.Username = null;
            // 
            // MyServiceInstaller
            // 
            this.MyServiceInstaller.Description = "First instance of my service.";
            this.MyServiceInstaller.DisplayName = "My Service - Instance 1";
            this.MyServiceInstaller.ServiceName = "MyService-1";
            this.MyServiceInstaller.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
            this.MyServiceInstaller.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(this.ServiceInstaller_Committed);
            this.MyServiceInstaller.AfterInstall += new InstallEventHandler(this.ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall);
            this.MyServiceInstaller.AfterUninstall += new InstallEventHandler(this.ServiceInstaller_AfterUnInstall);

            // 
            // ProjectInstaller
            // 
            this.Installers.AddRange(new Installer[] {
                this.MyServiceProcessInstaller,
                this.MyServiceInstaller
            });

        }

        public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {// This gets the named parameters passed in from your custom action
            string EXEFullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(EXEFullPath);   // get installation path

            try
            {
                SetAccess(path);

                string path2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(path).FullName, "instance2");
                string EXEFullPath2 = Path.Combine(path2, Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

                if (!Directory.Exists(path2))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path2);
                }

                SetAccess(path2);

                // Get the file contents of the directory to copy.
                FileInfo[] files = (new DirectoryInfo(path)).GetFiles();

                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    string temppath;

                    // Create the path to the new copy of the file.
                    temppath = Path.Combine(path2, file.Name);

                    // Copy the file.
                    file.CopyTo(temppath, true);
                }

                string Instance = "1";

                string Alltext = File.ReadAllText(EXEFullPath + ".config");
                // Rewrite config file - instance 1
                Alltext = Alltext.Replace("{Instance}", Instance);
                File.WriteAllText(EXEFullPath + ".config", Alltext);

                Instance = "2";

                Alltext = File.ReadAllText(EXEFullPath2 + ".config");
                // Rewrite config file - instance 2
                Alltext = Alltext.Replace("{Instance}", Instance);
                File.WriteAllText(EXEFullPath2 + ".config", Alltext);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            base.Install(stateSaver);
        }

        void SetAccess(string dir)
        {
            // Create security identifier for Local Service user; Local Service is used for the service at installation
            SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.LocalServiceSid, null);
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
            DirectorySecurity ds = di.GetAccessControl();
            // add a new file access rule w/ write/modify for all users to the directory security object

            ds.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(sid,
                                                  FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.Modify,
                                                  InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,   // all sub-dirs to inherit
                                                  PropagationFlags.None,
                                                  AccessControlType.Allow));                                            // Turn write and modify on
                                                                                                                        // Apply the directory security to the directory
            di.SetAccessControl(ds);
        }

        void ServiceInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {// This gets the named parameters passed in from your custom action
            using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(MyServiceInstaller.ServiceName))
            {
                sc.Start();     // start the service (instance 1) after installation
            }

            int exitCode;

            using (var process = new Process())
            {
                var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                string EXEFullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(EXEFullPath);   // get installation path

                string path2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(path).FullName, "instance2");
                string EXEFullPath2 = Path.Combine(path2, Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

                // tell Windows that the service should restart if it fails
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("create {0} start= auto binPath= \"{1}\" obj= \"{2}\" DisplayName= \"{3}\"", "MyService-2", EXEFullPath2, "NT AUTHORITY\\LocalService", "My Service - Instance 2");

                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            }

            if (exitCode != 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            else
            {
                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                    startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                    // Set the service description
                    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("description {0} \"{1}\"", "MyService-2", "Second instance of My Service.");

                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }

                if (exitCode != 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            if (exitCode == 0)
            {
                using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService-2"))
                {
                    sc.Start();     // start the service (instance 2) after installation
                }
            }
        }

        // right after service is installed, we set Recovery to restart after failures.
        void ServiceInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {
            int exitCode;

            using (var process = new Process())
            {
                var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                // tell Windows that the service should restart if it fails
                startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("failure \"{0}\" reset= 0 actions= restart/0", MyServiceInstaller.ServiceName);

                process.Start();
                process.WaitForExit();

                exitCode = process.ExitCode;
            }

            if (exitCode != 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            else
            {
                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                    startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                    // tell Windows that the service should restart if it fails
                    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("failure \"{0}\" reset= 0 actions= restart/0", "MyService-2");

                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }
            }

            if (exitCode != 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            else
            {
                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                    startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                    // reset Manager 1 service permissions
                    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("sdset {0} \"{1}\"", "MyService-1", "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRCRPWP;;;LS)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)");

                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }

                if (exitCode != 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            if (exitCode != 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            else
            {
                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                    startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                    // reset Manager 2 service permissions
                    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("sdset {0} \"{1}\"", "MyService-2", "D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRCRPWP;;;LS)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)");

                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }

                if (exitCode != 0)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }

        void ServiceInstaller_AfterUnInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
        {// This gets the named parameters passed in from your custom action
            try
            {
                using (ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("MyService-2"))
                {
                    sc.Stop();     // stop the service (instance 2) after uninstallation
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            try
            {
                int exitCode;

                using (var process = new Process())
                {
                    var startInfo = process.StartInfo;
                    startInfo.FileName = "sc";
                    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

                    // tell Windows that the service should restart if it fails
                    startInfo.Arguments = string.Format("delete MyService-2");

                    process.Start();
                    process.WaitForExit();

                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            try
            {
                string EXEFullPath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
                string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(EXEFullPath);   // get installation path

                string path2 = Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(path).FullName, "instance2");
                string EXEFullPath2 = Path.Combine(path2, Path.GetFileName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));

                Directory.Delete(path2, true);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller MyServiceProcessInstaller;
        private System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller MyServiceInstaller;
    }
}
```